# Marshalling a struct datatype as a return type from C++ Dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, marshalling, dllimport

I am having problem on getting the value of my search method from my define stack
from a C++ DLL to C# program here's my code

C++--------------------------------------------------------------

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) userCredential CallStackSeach(StackUser* pObject, userCredential item)
{
    return pObject->search(item);
}
```

Structure

```
typedef struct userInfo
{
    char* firstName;
    char* middleName;
    char* lastName;
    char* address;
    char* email;
};


typedef struct userCredential
{
    char* username;
    userInfo person;
    char* password;
    bool admin;

};
```

C#------------------------------------------------------------

Structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct userInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string firstName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string middleName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string lastName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string address;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string email;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct userCredential
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string username;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public userInfo person;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string password;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool admin;
}
```

//PInvoke

```
[DllImportAttribute("SystemMISO,dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="CallStackSearch")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
static private extern IntPtr CallStackSeach(IntPtr pObejct, userCredential item);
```

//FunctionWrapper

```
public userCredential StackSeach(userCredential item)
{         
   var ptr = CallStackSeach(this.ptrObject,item);
   return (userCredential)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(userCredential));
   //occur error
}
```

I am having an error fo `"Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt)."`

Comment: Did you copy from your code? Because it seems you are missing an 'r' in your method-name.